# Does chromecast have a list of recommended video encoding parameters?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

The only documentation references to media guidelines appears to be this one page from the Google Cast product page.

On that page it makes no references to encoding setting recommendations or restrictions, especially for the (in beta) adaptive bitrate protocols.  Apple has a set of recommendations for [HLS encoding settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-BITRATERECOMMENDATIONS), while Microsoft's Expression Encoder ships with a series of smooth streaming encoding presets.  Android also has a set of [encoding recommendations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations), that are similar to Apple's HLS recommendations with an added emphasis on the Google-Backed VP8 codec.

If we are intending to use the Styled Media Receiver or the Base Media Receiver, should we be following one of these encoding recommendations or is there something else available out there?  If there isn't an official recommendation, does anyone know of a non-official study of reliable settings?

On the same token, does anyone have similar information about Live Streams, as opposed to recorded streams?

I have noticed a fair amount of rate switching and buffering while playing HLS streams through the chromecast, while the same stream does not have issues while playing on the desktop or mobile device.  This makes me wonder if I should be serving a different subset of encoded files (lower bitrates, same keyframing) for the Cast device to use.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a set of recommendations and instead, we'd like to use the ones already provided by Apple and Microsoft. Namely:

- for HLS, a good starting point wold be Apple's recommendations. Note that chromecast requires every segment to start with a keyframe.
- for SmoothStreaming, Microsoft's recommendations should be used.
- in general, it is strongly recommended not to use any stream  exceeding 5 Mbs.